# Google Calendar API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, google-api

I'm trying to create an event in a private calendar with a server key.

This is what I have tried:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization = nil
client.key = 'SERVER_KEY_HERE'
service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
client.execute(api_method: service.events.insert, parameters: {calendarId: 'CALENDAR_ID', sendNotifications: true}, body: JSON.dump({summary: 'test event', description: '', location: '', start: {date: '2015-09-03'}, end: {date: '2015-09-04'}, attendees: []}), headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

However, the event doesn't get created and this is what I get in the console:

```
Google::APIClient::Request Result: 200
Decompressing gzip encoded response (154 bytes)
Decompressed (238 bytes)
Google::APIClient::Request Result: 401
```

I think I need to use a server key instead of a client key even though this is rails because the calendar is owned by person_a, and I don't want the user getting this page to have to sign-in as person_a or for person_a to allow anyone to modify the calendar outside of this page.

If I understand it correctly, if I use a client key, I would get a login page and be required to login as person_a to be able to modify this calendar.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "server key"?  you should be using a service account make sure you granted the service account email address access to the calendar.

Comment: Google's API works with "server keys" and "OAuth 2.0 client keys"; I presume I need to use a server key given the server is making a request on the coder's behalf instead of on the user's behalf.

Comment: Service account.  Make sure you gave the service account access to the Google Calendar by adding the email address as a user